# Seamless scrolling on parent when pointer is on iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, scroll

The problem occurs in FF. I have a iframe which is taller than the viewport height. Therefore parent page has scrolling bar on the right. When pointer is somewhere on the page (but not on iframe) the page scroll as I like. However, when I move pointer on iframe, the scrolling stops in Firefox (probably since iframe has no need for scrolling). Chrome works smoothly, ie. the page scrolls even if the pointer is on iframe.

How to achieve this "seamless" scrolling in FF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no solution exists to this problem except waiting FF to adjust itself.